# Nether in creative?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can you enter the nether in creative on pocket edition?
I took a very long time watching videos on how to actually build the portal,
 but I built it in creative. Now it won't activate and I'm starting to think 
it won't work in creative.

Comment: Did you use a Flint and Steel to light the portal?

Comment: I don't think there is a nether in PE. I think there is just a Nether Reactor.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Nether in Pocket Edition, there is an entirely different system of getting 'Nether Resources' called the [Nether Reactor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Reactor)